# No such file or directory when moving a file

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, mv

This command on ubuntu is giving no such file or directory error:

```
/# mv mongodb-linux-x86_64-$VERSION mongodb
mv: cannot stat 'mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.7': No such file or directory
```

even though both file and directory exist.
Any idea why? Thanks

**edit**

```
/# ls mongodb-linux-x86_64-* mongodb
mongodb:

mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.2-rc0:
GNU-AGPL-3.0  README  THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES  bin
```

Comment: Whats the output of `ls mongodb-linux-x86_64-* mongodb`?

Comment: @heemayl please see edit with the answer to your question.

Comment: check what VERSION is set to -- its probably set to 2.6.7, where as your dir has 2.6.2-rc0

Comment: That is an unusual `ls` output.  What shell are you using?  Try replacing your `ls` output with `ls -lad mongodb-linux-x86_64-* mongodb` which will hopefully be clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file (directory) name you have is `mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.2-rc0`, not `mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.7`.

The variable `VERSION` is being expanded to `2.6.7`, but the desired expansion as far as your directory name is concerned would be `2.6.2-rc0`.

So you need to either define variable as such, and do the `mv`-ing:

```
VERSION='2.6.2-rc0'
mv mongodb-linux-x86_64-"$VERSION" mongodb
```

Or just use the path directly:

```
mv mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.2-rc0 mongodb
```

Note that, environment variables are usually denoted as all uppercase letters, the user-defined variables (and shell variables) should not contains all-caps to avoid ambiguity.